# Unable to parse at line (near "-[setRouter,['@router']]")

Tags: symfony, service

I have the below services.yml configuration. What is wrong with my syntax?

```
parameters:
    #    parameter_name: value

    services:
      redirect.after.login:
          class: UserBundle\Redirection\AfterLoginFailureRedirection
          arguments: ["@http_kernel","@security.http_utils"]
          calls:
              -[setRouter,['@router']]
              -[setContainer,['@container']]
    #    service_name:
    #        class: AppBundle\Directory\ClassName
    #        arguments: ["@another_service_name", "plain_value", "%parameter_name%"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a space between `-` and `[`

```
parameters:
  services:
    redirect.after.login:
      class: UserBundle\Redirection\AfterLoginFailureRedirection
        arguments: ["@http_kernel","@security.http_utils"]
        calls:
          - [setRouter, ['@router']]
          - [setContainer, ['@container']]
```